# Matlab: adding value into initialized nested struct-cell

Tags: matlab, structure, cells

I have this structure

```
Data = struct('trials',{},'time',{},'theta_des',{},'vel_des',{},'trials_number',{},'sample_numbers',{});
Data(1).trials = cell(1,trials_number);
for i=1:trials_number
   Data.trials{i} = struct('theta',{},'pos_err',{},'vel',{},'vel_err',{},'f_uparm',{},'f_forearm',{},'m_uparm',{},'m_forearm',{},...
                           'current',{},'total_current',{},'control_output',{},'feedback',{},'feedforward',{},'kp',{});
end
```

but when I want to add a value

```
Data.trials{i}.theta = 27;
```

I get this error...

```
A dot name structure assignment is illegal when the structure is empty.  Use a subscript on the structure.
```

Any idea of how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: As an alternative solution, you should be able to do this: `Data.trials{i}.theta(1) = 27;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation of [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html), it says the following statement:

> `s = struct(field,value)` creates a structure array with the specified field and values.
>
> `...`
>
> `...`
>
> - If any `value` input is an empty cell array, {}, then output s is an empty (0-by-0) structure.

Because your fields are initialized to `{}`, these are empty cell arrays, you will get an empty structure, so you are not able to access into the structure as it's empty.  If you want to initialize the `struct`, use the empty braces instead `[]`.  In other words, in your `for` loop, do this:

```
for i=1:trials_number
    Data.trials{i} = struct('theta',[],'pos_err',[],'vel',[],'vel_err',[],'f_uparm',[],'f_forearm' [],'m_uparm',[],'m_forearm',[],...
    'current',[],'total_current',[],'control_output',[],'feedback',[],'feedforward',[],'kp',[]);
end
```

This should properly initialize the structure for you, and you can then access the fields accordingly.  As such, if I wanted to initialize `theta` in the first structure within your cell array:

```
Data.trials{1}.theta = 27;
```

This will now work.  You can verify the output by:

```
disp(Data.trials{1}.theta)

27
```

Comment: This works beautifully, this is the best answer I've found on the whole internet, thank's a lot!

Comment: @gaborous oh gee. :). Thanks a lot...  And you're welcome!

Comment: I think he can get around this with `Data = struct('trials',{{}} ,'time',{{}}, ` etc.