# Nested Cell Structure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I am attempting to organize a large amount of data into nested structures in MATLAB and I would like for each structure to contain a cell array but I get

> A dot name structure assignment is illegal when the structure is empty.  Use a subscript on the structure.

Example of code:

```
Year.Org1 = struct('Set1',{},'Set2',{});
Year.Org2 = struct('Set1',{},'Set2',{});
```

and then I want Set1/Set2/etc to be cell arrays of n-rows with column 1 str, column 2 str, column 3 value, and so on.

Any advice on initializing this structure and then accessing various parts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab: adding value into initialized nested struct-cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998644/matlab-adding-value-into-initialized-nested-struct-cell)

Comment: @Troy Not exactly a duplicate I think the OP needs `{{}}` and not `{[]}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single curly braces the structure is initialized empty. You can achieve what you want by doubling the curly braces:

```
Year.Org1 = struct('Set1',{{}},'Set2',{{}});
```

Best,

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as "solved" if it is the case by accepting the answer. It will tell the community that you no longer need help on that matter. You can upvote too, if you liked the answer :)

Comment: I tried to upvote it but I do not have 15 rep yet, sorry :(

Comment: Don't worry it's fine